# Javascript Not loading in custom module Odoo 8

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to include my custom javascript in my module but the js file is not getting loaded.

Below is my code:

js:

```
openerp.hr_timesheet_extended = function (instance) {

    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb,
        _t  = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;

    instance.hr_attendance.AttendanceSlider.include({
    // override methods
    });
};
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="hr_attendance assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/attendance.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you add the xml file to the `__openerp__.py`? Try writing the name of your module as the xml file name (`your_module_name.xml`) and replace the name of the template to `name="your_module_name assets"`. Do you get any error in the console of your browser? Write and example of a overriden method and try writing some console.log() to check if the file is executed

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you inherit any template and append your files to that template,

```
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
```

your files will be appended first then the other existing files, so whenever it will load it's won't found any existing files, this happens only in web xml inheritance.

**Solution:**

Add your file after all the base file.

```
<xpath expr="//script[@src='/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/notes.js']" position="after">
```

Give complete path in expr rather than "." only.

**Attention:**

Make sure the js/css source file are under hierarchy structure "static/src/js/" or "static/src/css/" in the root of the module folder.

Comment: But where exactly should my complete path start? from the position of current xml file or some specific position?

Comment: Complete path should start from addons folders path, I mean "/" is addons folder path, root = addons path which you have configured, so pos_restaurant is the module in addons, similarly you can set path for your custom module.

Comment: But if my src position is outside the addons path, can i use ../ to go back? I have tried but still 404... since my customized module is outside addons folder...

Comment: For example, my js/css folder is called A, A folder is at the same level with folder openerp, could you tell me what should my "expr" be here? Cause I may have to go back from my addons-path but i don't know how T_T

Comment: It should be within the module and module should be in addon path.

Comment: But I have modify the "addons-path" in config file to involve my own module into the project. And the js/css file is inside the module folder?

Comment: then it should work, make sure that hierarchy "static/src/js/" , "static/src/css/" must be followed

Comment: I got it... my problem is not following the "static/src/js" structure